# setting up angular material typings with angular 2 in visual studio 2017

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use angular material to set up dialogs. 
I am using using angular 2

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
```

I am setting up my app.ts like this.. ( I am only showing how I am injecting components)

```
var app = angular.module("App", ["ngRoute", "ngResource", "ui.bootstrap", "ngCookies", "ngAnimate", "ngSanitize",
"angularMoment", "ngMessages", "LeisureInsure.Admin", "ngLocationUpdate", "ladda"])
.config(LeisureInsure.Routes.configureRoutes)
```

Now I have installed angular material using this setup with npm

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

And I ran

> npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

Now this is the correct angular material for angular 2? there is also

https://material.angularjs.org
But am I correct in thinking this is only for angular js? not angular 2?

Now I am not sure how to register all the typings which are in 
node_modules\@angular\material
My typings are currently in 
Scripts\typings

Also with angular js it looked like I add angular material by just injecting ngMaterial into my components at the top, but with this version https://material.angular.io/ it looks like you add a component like this

```
export class TestDialog {
constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<TestDialog>) { }

closeDialog() {
    this.dialogRef.close('Pizza!');
}
}
```

This is an app.ts but it doesn't recognize MatDialogRef. thats down to the typings?

Comment: I added  import { MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material"; to the top of app.ts, that sorted it the typing issue.

Comment: I need to close this, I am going to use the JQuery UI with the typings.. its far less hassle than setting up angular material.

Comment: Angular is extremely easy to set up if you follow the [guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) and especially use Angular CLI. After that you can add in Angular Material following its [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) (which you already know about). Ignore anything you learned about AngularJS and Angular Material for AngularJS - they are two completely different platforms and from a code perspective they are very different (Angular is far easier than AngularJS IMO).

Comment: Thanks. When you say Angular CLI do you mean Angular 2?

Comment: No. I mean [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/). Just follow the Angular (2/4/5/6) [guide](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart).